# How can I dynamically set router options in a Meteor application using the iron router package?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I would like to set a route option label to that of the current url, e.g.

```
Router.route('/:_url', {
  label: '_url',
  action: function () {
    this.render('home');
  }
});
```

This is my helper:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.home.helpers({
    getLabel: function() {
      return Router.current().route.options.label;
    }
  });
}
```

This is my template:

```
<template name="home">
  hi
  {{getLabel}}
</template>
```

When I visit `locolhost:3000/alexander` I should see `hi alexander` however I see `hi _url`

How can I get the _url variable to correctly resolve so I see `hi alexander` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router.route("/:name", {
  name: "home",
  template: "home",
  data: function(){
    // this will create a new key myName on the route object for this route
    // and set the value to the name that the user entered in the path
    this.route.options.myName = this.params.name;
    return {
      label: this.params.name
    };
  }
});

// All routes are stored in the Router.routes array
// Loop through it to find the only one with a myName key and return the value

for (var i = 0; i < Router.routes.length; i++){
  if (Router.routes[i].options.myName){
    console.log(Router.routes[i].options.myName); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, 'this.route.options.myName = this.params.name' did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data context of your route to include the URL parameter like this :

JS

```
Router.route("/:name", {
  name: "home",
  template: "home",
  data: function(){
    return {
      label: this.params.name
    };
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="home">
  <h3>Hi {{label}}</h3>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am looking to store something in the route options object, not the data context. This is because I wish to recursively traverse previous routes to find a list of all routes, and create links to act as 'breadcrumbs' on my site. I am following the answer in this tutorial: http://www.codedisqus.com/CSVjVPVekU/meteor-iron-router-to-create-breadcrumbs.html, which leaves out how to handle dynamic route labels.

Comment: You want to store a name in the `route` object?